# boost::object_pool is too slow

Tags: c++, boost

try to use boost::object_pool for create pool objects (vector int*)

```
    // new allocator for each object 
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
        {
            std::vector<int*> coll;
            coll.reserve(1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
                coll.emplace_back(new int(i));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                delete coll[i];

            coll.clear();
        }

        auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        std::cout << "execute time duration = " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
    }

    // boost::object_pool. for create boost::object_pool operator new call onse time
    {
        auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        boost::object_pool<int> pool{ 2000,0 };
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
        {
            std::vector<int*> coll;
            coll.reserve(1000);

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                coll.emplace_back(pool.construct(i));

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
                pool.destroy(coll[i]);

            coll.clear();
        }

        auto diff = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
        std::cout << "execute time duration = " << std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(diff).count() << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
    }
```

result

laptop configuration 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11370H @ 3.30GHz 3.30 GHz 16,0 ГБ
vs2022

debug
execute time duration = 13.6784 milliseconds
execute time duration = 1488.07 milliseconds

release
execute time duration = 4.4204 milliseconds
execute time duration = 37.3916 milliseconds

I expect boost::object_pool will be faster

Answer (score 1):

I think pool allocators shine for bulk allocations. You're individually allocating small objects (but bulk deallocating).

### Reproducing The Slowness

I morphed your scenario into a version that can be written generically:

```
struct your_scenario {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        Alloc alloc;

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            std::vector<T*> coll;
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                auto p = alloc.allocate(1);
                alloc.construct(p, i);
                coll.push_back(p);
            }

            for (auto el : coll) {
                alloc.destroy(el);
                alloc.deallocate(el, 1);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};
```

You you can run both allocators side-by-side with

```
using standard  = std::allocator<T>;
using pool      = boost::pool_allocator<T, UserAllocator, Mutex, 2ull*N, 0>;

bench(your_scenario::run<T, standard>, "standard");
bench(your_scenario::run<T, pool>,     "pool");
```

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/941f384a72e988e6)**, printing

```
 106ms  standard
1706ms  pool
```

(or locally for me, 20 vs. 1120ms). So yeah, that confirms the slowness.

### Comparing Scenarious

Let's introduce some varying parameters:

- I wager that `int` is only a stand-in for a more "involved" type that makes sense to dynamically allocate element-wise. Let's compare with such a type:

  ```
   struct Complex {
       std::string state;
       Complex(int init) : state(std::to_string(init)) { }
   };
  ```
- Also, let's compare the `NextSize/MaxSize` tunings as you had them overriden from the defaults for the pool.
- Let's compare with `fast_pool_allocator` which doesn't favor bulk allocations as much, see [e.g.](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.pool):

  > Both allocators are used in the same way, but `boost::pool_allocator`
  > should be preferred if you are requesting contiguous segments.
  > `boost::fast_pool_allocator` can be used if segments are requested one
  > by one. Grossly simplified: You use `boost::pool_allocator` for
  > `std::vector` and `boost::fast_pool_allocator` for `std::list`.

As a halway point, let's check: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f8a9d6c489c7e85)**

```
1754ms  default tuning  Complex pool
1735ms  custom tuning   Complex pool
1717ms  default tuning  int pool
1707ms  custom tuning   int pool
 137ms  custom tuning   Complex standard
 135ms  default tuning  Complex standard
 133ms  default tuning  Complex fast_pool
 132ms  custom tuning   Complex fast_pool
 120ms  default tuning  int standard
 112ms  custom tuning   int fast_pool
 112ms  default tuning  int fast_pool
 105ms  custom tuning   int standard
```

Okay. So far we found that regardless of tuning the `fast_pool_allocator` makes a huge difference. Standard library is still faster.

### Broadening Scenarios

If we vary the scenario code itself, and maybe also the UserAllocator/Mutex choice we can broaden the picture further. Lets start with a naive scenario as I'd more typically expect it:

```
struct more_typical {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            std::vector<T, Alloc> coll;
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                coll.emplace_back(i);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};
```

Indeed, here I'd expect the fast allocator to make less of a difference (or even be slower).

Let's also add a minor tweak - that may or may not be applicable to your application, by reusing the vector across iterations:

```
struct optimizing {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        std::vector<T, Alloc> coll;

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                coll.emplace_back(i);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};
```

Because this optimization is tentative for your use-case, I'll only use it in combination with the aggressive custom tuning of UserAllocator and Mutex, just to see the width of the field.

### Full Listing And Results

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7a0740f727001a20)**

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/object_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

constexpr int      N          = 1'000;
constexpr unsigned iterations = 2'000;

struct your_scenario {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        Alloc alloc;

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            std::vector<T*> coll;
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                auto p = alloc.allocate(1);
                alloc.construct(p, i);
                coll.push_back(p);
            }

            for (auto el : coll) {
                alloc.destroy(el);
                alloc.deallocate(el, 1);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};

struct more_typical {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            std::vector<T, Alloc> coll;
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                coll.emplace_back(i);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};

struct optimizing {
    template <typename T, typename Alloc> static void run() {
        std::vector<T, Alloc> coll;

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < iterations; ++j) {
            coll.reserve(N);

            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                coll.emplace_back(i);
            }

            coll.clear();
        }
    }
};

namespace { // benchmark helper
    auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    static std::multimap<int, std::string, std::greater<>> results;

    template <typename F> void bench(F f, std::string_view label) {
        auto start = now();
        f();
        results.emplace((now() - start) / 1ms, label);
    }

    void bench_report() {
        for (auto [dur, label] : results)
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << dur << "ms\t" << label << "\n";

        results.clear();
    }
} // namespace

template <typename Scenario, typename T,
          /* additional tuning? */
          typename UserAllocator = boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete, //
          typename Mutex         = boost::details::pool::default_mutex,      //
          size_t NextSize        = 32,                                       //
          size_t MaxSize         = 0>
void exercise_for() {
    using standard  = std::allocator<T>;
    using pool      = boost::pool_allocator<T, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>;
    using fast_pool = boost::fast_pool_allocator<T, UserAllocator, Mutex, NextSize, MaxSize>;

    std::string const scenario = boost::core::demangle(typeid(Scenario).name());
    std::string const type     = boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name());

#define LABEL(T, Alloc)                                                                            \
    bench(Scenario::template run<T, Alloc>, scenario + "\t" + type + "\t" #Alloc);
    LABEL(T, standard);
    LABEL(T, pool);
    LABEL(T, fast_pool);
}

struct Complex {
    std::string state;
    Complex(int init) : state(std::to_string(init)) { }
};

int main() {
#define TUNING , boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete, boost::details::pool::default_mutex, 2ull*N, 0
    exercise_for<your_scenario, int TUNING>();
    exercise_for<your_scenario, Complex TUNING>();
    //bench_report();
#undef TUNING

#define TUNING
    exercise_for<more_typical, int TUNING>();
    exercise_for<more_typical, Complex TUNING>();
    //bench_report();
#undef TUNING

#define TUNING , boost::default_user_allocator_new_delete, boost::details::pool::null_mutex, 32, 0
    exercise_for<optimizing, int TUNING>();
    exercise_for<optimizing, Complex TUNING>();
    //bench_report();
#undef TUNING
    bench_report();
}
```

Printing

```
1731ms  your_scenario   Complex pool
1719ms  your_scenario   int pool
 137ms  your_scenario   Complex standard
 129ms  your_scenario   Complex fast_pool
 115ms  your_scenario   int fast_pool
 107ms  your_scenario   int standard
  32ms  more_typical    Complex fast_pool
  31ms  more_typical    Complex pool
  28ms  more_typical    Complex standard
  25ms  optimizing      Complex standard
  24ms  optimizing      Complex pool
  23ms  optimizing      Complex fast_pool
   5ms  more_typical    int pool
   5ms  more_typical    int fast_pool
   5ms  optimizing      int standard
   4ms  more_typical    int standard
   3ms  optimizing      int fast_pool
   2ms  optimizing      int pool
```

Or, locally:

```
1127ms  your_scenario   Complex pool
1119ms  your_scenario   int pool
  45ms  your_scenario   Complex fast_pool
  30ms  your_scenario   int fast_pool
  30ms  your_scenario   Complex standard
  21ms  more_typical    Complex pool
  21ms  more_typical    Complex fast_pool
  20ms  your_scenario   int standard
  19ms  optimizing      Complex pool
  18ms  more_typical    Complex standard
  18ms  optimizing      Complex standard
  18ms  optimizing      Complex fast_pool
   2ms  more_typical    int pool
   2ms  more_typical    int fast_pool
   1ms  more_typical    int standard
   1ms  optimizing      int standard
   1ms  optimizing      int pool
   1ms  optimizing      int fast_pool
```

At least we can see that std::allocator is longer just faster in all scenarios.

### Summary/Conclusion

I'll let you draw your own conclusions. The [linked article](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.pool) might be the best resource on Boost Pool I know off, but beware of the comments, it's still "Here be dragons" territory.

I admit I typically never use Boost Pool. I'll prefer a `std::pmr::memory_resource` approach. Perhaps there is a scenario like [described here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/appendices/faq.html#boost_pool.appendices.faq.why_should_i_use_pool_) where I'd revisit the idea:

> #### Why should I use Pool?
>
> Using Pools gives you more control over how memory is used in your program. For example, you could have a situation where you want to allocate a bunch of small objects at one point, and then reach a point in your program where none of them are needed any more. Using pool interfaces, ***you can choose to run their destructors or just drop them off into oblivion***; the pool interface will guarantee that there are no system memory leaks.

[emphasis mine]